# Trouble in manipulating the data for treeview in tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

everyone. Let me first paste the code.

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM c20 WHERE Position = 'chain';")
data1 = c.fetchall()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM c20 WHERE Position = 'center';")
data2 = c.fetchall()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM c20 WHERE Position = 'Total';")
data3 = c.fetchall()

data1 = p_mod.list_multiply(data, copies_data)
data2 = p_mod.list_multiply(data2, copies_data)
data3 = p_mod.list_multiply(data3, copies_data)
    
meta_data = [data1, data2, data3]
n = 0
while n != 3:
    for i in meta_data:
        my_tree.insert(parent="", index="end", iid=n, text=f"{n + 1}", values=i)
        n += 1


if n == 3:
    my_tree.pack(pady=20)

root1.mainloop()
```

This is the code where I need to fetch queries regarding a requirement and the output required is as follows:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("userdata.db")
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute("SELECT * FROM c20 WHERE Position = 'chain';")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00000221DA432F80>
>>> data1 = c.fetchall()         
>>> data1
[('chain', 100, 350, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
```

I have also used a remote function named **p_mod.list_multiply()**.
The function looks like this:

```
def list_multiply(list_input, number):
    new_list = []
    list_input = list(list_input)[0]
    list_input1 = list_input[1 : -1]
    for i in list_input1:
        data = int(i) * number
        new_list.append(data)

    if list_input[0] == 'chain':
        new_list.insert(0, 'chain')

    elif list_input[0] == 'center':
        new_list.insert(0, 'center')

    elif list_input[0] == 'Total':
        new_list.insert(0, 'Total')

    new_list = tuple(new_list)
    return new_list
```

Now the problem arises...
Whenever I try to run the code with same outputs(data1, data2,...) using the function remotely from the main code,
it runs successfully, but whenever I am trying to run the script inside the main program it gives me an error.

Error is as follows:

```
PS D:\RM INCORPORATION\RM Software DEV Company Pvt\Jewellery App> & C:/Users/ONE/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "d:/RM INCORPORATION/RM Software DEV Company Pvt/Jewellery App/contact.py"
h
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ONE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\RM INCORPORATION\RM Software DEV Company Pvt\Jewellery App\contact.py", line 53, in select
    data1 = p_mod.list_multiply(data, copies_data)
  File "d:\RM INCORPORATION\RM Software DEV Company Pvt\Jewellery App\p_mod.py", line 15, in list_multiply
    data = int(i) * number
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'h'
```

Let me show you the output used with the function remotely, from the main code...

```
PS D:\RM INCORPORATION\RM Software DEV Company Pvt\Jewellery App> & C:/Users/ONE/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "d:/RM INCORPORATION/RM Software DEV Company Pvt/Jewellery App/p_mod.py"
('chain', 200, 700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) ('center', 222, 826, 82, 124, 98, 70, 756, 2, 2, 6, 8, 24, 24, 16, 0, 0) ('Total', 422, 1526, 82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1878, 70)
```

Then what is the problem dude?
Eagerly waiting someone's reply

Comment: It means the 'h' is not an `int`. What I think its, they looped through 'Chain' and got 'h' and couldnt convert it to `int` because its not. This might just be mistake with `list_multiply()` and not the `Treeview`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overwritten `list_input` by the following line in `list_multiply()`:

```
list_input = list(list_input)[0]
```

Therefore, `list_input` will be a string after that.

Just remove this line will solve the issue.

Also the following line:

```
list_input1 = list_input[1 : -1]
```

will not copy the last item of `list_input` into `list_input1`.

It should be

```
list_input1 = list_input[1:]
```

---

`list_multiply()` can be simplified as below:

```py
def list_multiply(list_input, number):
    new_list = tuple(int(x)*number for x in list_input[1:])
    return (list_input[0],) + new_list
```

Comment: I am having trouble in working with this code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65735774/how-to-get-data-under-the-same-level-of-function-defined?noredirect=1#comment116225046_65735774

Comment: If you have issue regarding the type of database I have, you can visit https://github.com/adorabletrooper/Sabir-Jewellery-Works-/blob/main/Jewellery%20App/userdata.db