# Why is my treeview in the tkinter shows this?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

Currently the bug seems to be loosening it's position from my project. I have a last bug which I need to fix in order to complete my project.

Code looks like this:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM c20 WHERE Position = 'chain';")
        data1 = c.fetchall()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM c20 WHERE Position = 'center';")
        data2 = c.fetchall()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM c20 WHERE Position = 'Total';")
        data3 = c.fetchall()

        data1 = p_mod.list_multiply(data, int(copies_data))
        data2 = p_mod.list_multiply(data2, int(copies_data))
        data3 = p_mod.list_multiply(data3, int(copies_data))
    
        meta_data = [data1, data2, data3]
        n = 0
        while n != 3:
            for i in meta_data:
                my_tree.insert(parent="", index="end", iid=n, text=f"{n + 1}", values=i)
                n += 1


        if n == 3:
            my_tree.pack(pady=20)

        root1.mainloop()
```

The first input got displayed successfully inside the treeview.
But the following inputs were not displayed inside the treeview widget.
[image]
The input for the second 'data2' is:

```
[('center', 111, 413, 41, 62, 49, 35, 378, 1, 1, 3, 4, 12, 12, 8, 0, 0, 0)]
```

The **p_mod()** Code:

```
def list_multiply(list_input, number):
    new_list = tuple(int(x)*number for x in list_input[1:])
    return (list_input[0],) + new_list
```

Where am i getting wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just tried but it says 'copies_data' is not defined in the global scope.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri How will saying `copies_data` inside `select` help? `global` is to be used where the data is defined or declared(or changed) inside the function. Here the OP have to run `multiple()` first and then `select()`, without `multiple()` running the variable and the globalization will remain undetected. Why not just use `data1=p_mod.list_multiply(data, copies_entry.get())` and so on?

Comment: should i post the entire script for your convenience?

Comment: Did you define `copies_data` in the global scope?

Comment: I just edited the question, now plz find the issue...

Comment: Is that your real password there? Recommend removing it.

Comment: Did you try out `data1=p_mod.list_multiply(data, copies_entry.get())`, what error did you get?

Comment: Mate, I need to have that value only when I have pressed "set_btn", which will take the data from copies_entry.

Comment: You need to define `copies_data` inside `contact_dis()` and add `nonlocal copies_data` at the beginning of `multiple()`.

Comment: Your solution worked for me, but now I am facing another bug which seems to be the last bug of this project.